# How can I put repo A under version control with commit history from cloned repo B?

Tags: git, repository

I have 2 repositories- repo A and repo B. Repo B is a git clone of A (Repo A is the origin for repo B). These are private repositories and I am the only one using them. 
At some point in time, repo A stopped being under version control. It has had several changes made to it and all git related data has been lost (except for what is in repo B). It’s probably easier if you imagine repo B as being an old outdated backup of repo A.

I imagine this is how the 2 repos would look in pictorial form.

```
1---2    repo B
     \
      3  repo A
```

Using git, **I would like to put repo A back under version control, but I’d like to include the history of commit changes stored in repo B.** 
Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `A` is now just a directory with no `.git` or other versioning information...

```
# Make A a git repo
cd A
git init .

# Commit the current state
git add .
git commit -m "Commit A"

# Add B as a remote, and pull it in
git remote add B /path/to/B
git pull B master
```

Note - the final pull may result in a number of conflicts, depending on who A and B have diverged over time, that may need to be manually fixed up.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, but I made a small change.  Repo A and B shared the same development history for the first 2 commits (in the pictogram). When I ran `git init .` I was essentially doing the 3rd commit, so afterwards I used `git pull -s recursive -X ours B master` then `git add .` because I didn't want any differences in repo B to overwrite repo A and I didn't want to manually go through the conflicts one by one.